# Extract main text from any webpage using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing some code (Python) to scrape text from web pages. My goal is to find a way to filter/delete the paragraphs on webpages that are not in the main article (e.g. advertisement, links to other articles, etc.).

So far I've been using the `.find_all("p")` command to extract only paragraphs from the text, which although successful also scrapes a lot of rudimentary paragraphs which are not in the main/body of each article. This is my code now:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLs = [
"https://www.elsoldetoluca.com.mx/local/proponen-sistemas-para-captar-agua-pluvial-en-el-edomex-6585661.html",
"https://www.elsoldetoluca.com.mx/local/agua-de-acuifero-del-valle-de-toluca-solo-debe-ser-para-uso-de-consumo-humano-especialista-4146232.html"
        ]

for url in URLs:
    req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    page = urlopen(req)
    paragraphs = []
    htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'lxml')    
    for para in htmlParse.find_all("p"):
        paragraph = para.get_text().replace("\n", " ")
        paragraphs = paragraphs + [paragraph]
         
    text  = str("\n\n".join(paragraphs))
```

So I'm looking for a clever way to filter out the paragraphs that are not in the main article. It is essential that this method can be applied on *any* webpage, since I'm using this code on ~100 random websites. Things I've been looking into already is to filter paragraphs containing certain words, however, I would rather not do this because this way a lot of information/paragraphs are left out. Also, I've been looking at leaving out HTML sections with certain names (such as https://matix.io/extract-text-from-webpage-using-beautifulsoup-and-python/), but I find this is not very effective...

Anyone any tips on how to do this elegantly? Thanks!

Comment: You need to find the “root” element of the main article in your HTML, maybe an `<article>` element or a `<div class="article">`… then you can search for the paragraphs from this root element using the way you do.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, yeah so that's the tricky part right. I know how to do this for ONE page, but to make this universal? Many URLs use different names for this

Comment: use recursive=False  in find_all("p")

Comment: @BharatAgrawal implemented your suggestion, now I have no text at all. Seems to be not working

Comment: use re for class name

Comment: @BharatAgrawal can you post an example of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no smart way to tackle this problem. Every website has its own structure and own conventions. You might try blacklist approaches with some regex, but none of them will make you happy. I know your question is asking how to do this with bs4, but I will suggest another way to do this, which is trafilatura as shown here:

```
pip install trafilatura
```

```py
import trafilatura
downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url('your url here')
trafilatura.extract(downloaded)
```

which returns the clean content of the page as a string, and fast!

reference here: https://trafilatura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That sounds interesting.. I will look into it and let you know, thanks!